# How to add and subtract two datetime values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one tell me how to add and subtract two `Datetime` objects?

this my code

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxtime1.Text);
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxtime2.Text);

if (d2 < d1)
{
   DateTime d3 = new DateTime();
   d3= d3.Date.AddHours(24);
   TimeSpan ts = d3 - d1;
   string values = ts.ToString();
   DateTime d5 = Convert.ToDateTime(values);
   DateTime d4 = d5;
   TimeSpan ts1 = d4 - d2;
   TextBox24.Text=ts1.ToString();
   // ...
```

actually these two times are the departure and arrival times. i want to get estimated time by et=d2-d1 and if d2

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the date subtraction? the number of days, hours, weeks?

Comment: your code is all over the place.  I have the feeling that this is homework.  Can you precisely describe what you are trying to accomplish, with input and output values?

Comment: Your formula is not clear at all. Are you trying to subtract the total number of hours from two dates to 24?

Comment: actually these two times are the departure and arrival times. i want to get estimated time by et=d2-d1 and if d2<d1 i want et= 24(hrs)-d2+d1

Comment: @Crono i want the difference of two times like 09:00 - 03:00=06:00 and same for 09:00 + 03:00= 12:00

Comment: @Crono these arent the dates these are time like d1=03:00 and d2=09:00 i want to get estimated time if (d2>d1) i want d2-d1 et=(06:00) elseif(d2<d1) i want 24(hrs)-d2+d1 u got it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxtime1.Text);
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxtime2.Text);

if (d2 < d1)
{
    TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) + (d2 - d1);
    // ... do as you please with the result
}
```

Comment: thanks man its working fine u r the best ;)

Comment: You're welcome can I get a vote up, or at least marked as answer?

Comment: well its my first ever post here so can u please tell me what are you talking about

Comment: @user3430584 look at the left of each answer. You can vote on them and choose one as the right answer.

Comment: @focuspark TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) + (d2 - d1);  i actually want TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - (d2 + d1); but this gives Error Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime' how is it possible?

Comment: @meeru what logic would you use to add two dates together? The concept makes no sense. Subtraction of dates provides the difference between as a TimeSpan. What are you trying to achieve by adding two dates?

Comment: @focuspark these arent the dates these are time like d1=03:00 and d2=09:00 i want to get estimated time if (d2>d1) i want d2-d1 et=(06:00) elseif(d2<d1) i want 24(hrs)-d2+d1 u got it now?

Comment: @meeru a DateTime is more like "last Thursday at 2pm", not just a number of hours. If you want a number of hours, you need a TimeSpan.

I think what you really want is to check if d2 > d1; then tmp = d2, d2 = d1, d1 = tmp; then proceed as normal.

Comment: @focuspark but the time spam doesnt allow me to add using '+' operands. actually i want to add two times like 09:00 + 03:00=12:00 and than i want to subtract it from 24 hrs like 24 hrs'-'12:00= 12:00

Comment: @meeru you are treating DateTime like a TimeSpan. What do you get from adding "Jan 2, 2014 06:00" and "Feb 4, 1992 14:00"? They cannot be added. Instead use subtraction to discover the different between the two dates and work with that.

Comment: @focuspark thanks man for your time i did it by time span.. u opened my mind actually it was dead beacuse of united 3-0 lost to liverpool  :(

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` methods like `AddDays` and `AddHours` - which you already are using - also accepts negative values.

Therefore, if for example you wanted to remove 12 hours from a date, you could do this:

```
var newDate = oldDate.AddHours(-12);
```

That is ONE way of doing it; depending on your requirements you may want to get `TimeSpan` objects using `DateTime.Subtract` method:

```
var timeSpan = aDate.Subtract(anotherDate);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want, in hours, the difference between two dates, you can do this:

```
var totalHours = Math.Abs(arrivalDateTime.Subtract(departureDateTime).TotalHours);
```

Regardless of which date is the highest value you'll always get the total hours as a positive number.

Be aware though that if more than a day separates the two value the result may be higher than 24. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: when i use time spam it doesnt allow me to add using '+' on the other hand it allows me to subtract with '-'

Comment: @user3430584 I think you need to make your requirements clearer here. Edit your original post to give an example of input and how the expected output should look.

Comment: thanks for ur help i did it with this if (d2 < d1)
{
    TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) + (d2 - d1);
    // ... do as you please with the result
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DateTime.Subtract
DateTime.Add
```